# UIBarButtonItem crashes my application in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have already implemented my button:

```
import UIKit

class ShareButton {

    var status_title: String!
    var status_content: String!

    var button: UIBarButtonItem!

    init(status_title: String ,status_content: String) {
        button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: Selector("btn"))        
        self.status_title = status_title
        self.status_content = status_content
    }

    func btn()
    {
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        var can_open = application.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "whatsapp://")!)
        if (can_open) {
            let url_string = "whatsapp://send?text=" + status_content
            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: url_string)!
            application.openURL(url)
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "You don't have WhatsApp"
            alert.message = "You need WhatsApp to share this status"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Got it")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
}
```

But when I hit the button, the application crashes...

I'll be happy for some help,
Thanks a lot for your help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIVqn.png

Comment: Never say "the application crashes". Say what line the crash is on and what the console message is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your ShareButton class does not derive from NSObject. Its internals are therefore invisible to Cocoa, which cannot call into it - it can't find your `btn` method. You have two choices:

- Derive ShareButton from NSObject: `class ShareButton : NSObject {`
- Or, expose `btn` to Objective-C: `@objc func btn() {`

Comment: Actually you have two further choices, but I'm not going to say here what they are. For more info, see the discussion of this topic in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_selectors

Answer (score 0):

Once had a very similar problem, the thing that worked for me was adding a colon in the selector. Try change:

> button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: Selector("btn"))

to

> button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: Selector("btn:"))

Comment: I have tried it before, thanks for helping me but it doesn't work :(